# Client side script reference in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between these two script referneces

1.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="/Shared/scripts/CallMethod1.js"/>
        </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
...
</form></body>
```

2.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Shared/scripts/CallMethod1.js"></script>
```

Are both related or perform entirely different things?

Answer (score 0):

Both are different. The second one is unconditional call to Script. It will be registered with the page at the position it is called. Where as in the first one you can control the loading of the script like LoadScriptsBeforeUI="False", also in fact you have handle (reference)
 to the scripts in code behind too.